# SharedPreferences wont save after restart

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

My score saves if I leave my app with the back button, but if I close the app by force the score is not saved. How to fix a problem like this?

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("level1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.clear();
        prefsEditor.putInt("score", scores);
        prefsEditor.commit();
```

Comment: where you are saving score?

Comment: Why do you `clear()` the preferences each time?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K what do you mean?

Comment: @still_learning  I just found it in a example of how it should help to save data but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Arina : i mean where you are using current code for saving values

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: Sorry I don't really understand im just a beginner. Don't I save values in this sharedPreferences code? I have my score in public static int scores = 0; and increase it by ++ everytime I score. I create che scaredPreferences in onCreate

Comment: @ArinaŠlepaitė: use posted code in `onStop` method of Activity then check it's saving or not on application stop

Comment: Btw. There is better to use apply() method instead of commit() method.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK HI. I tried creating it on onStop. It works. Hovewer, now It shows me the score only when I restart the app. I need to show it instantly too.

Comment: @ArinaŠlepaitė: i'm not getting you please explain more

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK. My problem was that when I play a game and get the score it is immediately displayed in my activity, but only until I restart the app. After that the score is gone. Now when I add my code to the onStop method I don't see my code until I restart the app. I need that my code would be displayed  immediately after the game and when I open my app later.

Comment: @ArinaŠlepaitė: then also save score in SharedPreferences when game is ended or moving to other screen

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Do you mean I should save the code in onStop and onCreate too? That doesn't work.

Comment: @ArinaŠlepaitė: what you are doing when game is over?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have 3 questions. When you nswer the last question alertDialog opens and you choose to end the game or to restart. If you end the game you go to other activity and the score there should be displayed./

Comment: @ArinaŠlepaitė: then on `end the game` Button click save value again.

Comment: @ArinaŠlepaitė: have you tired to save value on end or restart button click ?

Comment: @ArinaŠlepaitė: Welcome, _I'm glad I was able to help :)_